# ValueError: Filter must not be larger than the input

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras

I am pretty new to machine learning so I am playing around with examples and such.
The image size specified in the code is (28,28)
But for some reason I keep getting the same ValueError
I cant figure out why this is happening.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1337) # for reproducibility

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

batch_size = 128 # Number of images used in each optimization step
nb_classes = 10 # One class per digit
nb_epoch = 35 # Number of times the whole data is used to learn

# Read the train and test datasets
train = pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv").values
test  = pd.read_csv("../input/test.csv").values

# Reshape the data to be used by a Theano CNN. Shape is
# (nb_of_samples, nb_of_color_channels, img_width, img_heigh)
X_train = train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test = test.reshape(test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
y_train = train[:, 0] # First data is label (already removed from X_train)

# Make the value floats in [0;1] instead of int in [0;255]
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices (ie one-hot vectors)
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)

#Display the shapes to check if everything's ok
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('Y_train shape:', Y_train.shape)
print('X_test shape:', X_test.shape)

model = Sequential()
# For an explanation on conv layers see http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv
# By default the stride/subsample is 1
# border_mode "valid" means no zero-padding.
# If you want zero-padding add a ZeroPadding layer or, if stride is 1 use border_mode="same"
model.add(Convolution2D(12, 5, 5, border_mode='valid',input_shape=(1,img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# For an explanation on pooling layers see http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#pool
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.15))

model.add(Convolution2D(24, 5, 5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.15))

# Flatten the 3D output to 1D tensor for a fully connected layer to accept the input
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(180))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes)) #Last layer with one output per class
model.add(Activation('softmax')) #We want a score simlar to a probability for each class

# The function to optimize is the cross entropy between the true label and the output (softmax) of the model
# We will use adadelta to do the gradient descent see http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#ada
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=["accuracy"])

# Make the model learn
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1)

# Predict the label for X_test
yPred = model.predict_classes(X_test)

# Save prediction in file for Kaggle submission
np.savetxt('mnist-pred.csv', np.c_[range(1,len(yPred)+1),yPred], delimiter=',', header = 'ImageId,Label', comments = '', fmt='%d')
```

Comment: Can you add a traceback of the error?

Comment: I would ask if you're using tensorflow or theano. I had a similar error with a canned example and I fixed it by changing input_shape=(1,img_rows, img_cols) to input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols,1) in a couple of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is with the convolution sizes used. Convolution operations usually **reduce** dimension of the image. Similarly - each pooling operation reduces the size. You have very small images yet applied model architecture which has been designed for a bigger ones, thus at some point, after one of the convolutions/poolings you actually have a smaller outputed image than a following filter size, and this is an ill-defined operation.

To temporarly fix the problem - remove second convolution and maxpooling layers, since these operations (with parameters provided) cannot be performed on such small data. In general you should first understand how convolution works, and not apply someone elses model, since the parameters are crucial for good performance - if you apply transformations which reduce resolution to much - you will be unable to learn anything. Thus once you have some intuition how convolution works you can go back and try different architectures, but there is no one, "magical" equation to figure out the architecture, thus I cannot provide you with parameters that will "just work" - start with removing this additional convolution and pooling, and than go back and try other possibilities once you have better understanding of your data and model.

Comment: Okay, so I tried the program after removing the maxpooling and convolution layers both,the program executed successfully when I removed the maxpooling! What does maxpooling do exactly?

Comment: It moves a window through the image and takes the maximum value from the window. Efficiently it reduces the resolution of image by giving some invariance to small translations in the image processing

Comment: Butthe thing is the second conv is the problem. It reduced the resolution so extremely that your image is now smaller than 5x5 pixels. This is why max pooling woth 5x5 window failed. In other words removing just pooling rather masks the issue than resolves it